# Pulley system on a double inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image: The system]

(Lets say, say static friction is $\mu_s$, and kinetic friction is $\mu_k$ for both of them)

What is the detailed definition of static friction according to this picture? When the system starts to accelerate?

I know how to solve the system when there is only one mass on inclined plane and other is hanged.

But in this case I am confusing on "when the mass1 & mass2 starts to move"

In my case: 
        The system starts to move towards m1 when

> m1 * g * sin(angle1) > m2 * g * sin(angle2) + $\mu_s$ * m1 * g * cos(angle1) +$\mu_s$ * m2 * g * cos(angle2)
>
> a = m1 * g * sin(angle1) - m2 * g * sin(angle2) + $\mu_k$ * m1 * g * cos(angle1) +$\mu_k$ * m2 * g * cos(angle2)

a is acceleration towards downward in m1

Comment: I don't see what your question is. A definition is something you can simply look up. Or are you looking for algebraic expressions of both $\mu$ in function of your drawn system?

Comment: **1)** [Definition here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Static_friction). **2)** No. **P.S.** What forces do you see acting on each of m1 and m2? **P.P.S.** You can (and should) edit new information into your answer and use MathJax to enter formulae.